# How to filter between seperate values of month and year in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table as shown below:

```
ID |  Month |    Year      |   Data 
 1 |   01   |    2019      |    125
 2 |   09   |    2019      |    133
 3 |   09   |    2017      |    356 
 4 |   12   |    2018      |    567 
 5 |   10   |    2020      |    123
```

I want to get the rows between **12-2018** to **09-2019**.

So I have the values

startMonth = 12,

startYear = 2018,

endMonth = 09

endYear = 2019.

How do i filter the data in between?

This is what I have so far:

```
$data = Revenue::where('month', '>=', $fromMonth)
    ->where('month', '<=', $toMonth)
    ->where('year', '>=', $fromYear)
    ->where('year', '<=', $toYear)
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->paginate(6);
```

Comment: Even when its Christmas Day. First you write a query and then if it does not do what you want show it to us#

Comment: Just provide code from your controller

Comment: `WHERE (month = 12 AND year = 2018) OR (month <= 9 AND year = 2019)`

Comment: $data = Revenue::where('month', '>=', $fromMonth)->where('month', '<=', $toMonth)->where('year', '>=', $fromYear)->where('year', '<=', $toYear)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate(6); I wrote this code but since month is not always lower.. it doesnt seem to work

Comment: i want to get the rows between the user input month and year values from the above given table

Comment: Is there a reason you're storing the month and year separately rather than using a date field?

Comment: yeah. it was given to me as a requirement

Comment: I think `whereBetween` is the same as questions' code. I don't know why so many people upvote that. And it will not included the 2019-01 to 2019-07

Comment: Did any of the below answers solve your problem or are you still having issues?

Comment: I found your solution below perfect for the problem i had

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: yeah. thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of [CONCAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp) and [STR_TO_DATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp) to achieve what you're after:

```
$data = Revenue
        ::whereRaw("STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year, '-', month, '-', 1), '%Y-%m-%d') >= ?", "$fromYear-$fromMonth-1")
        ->whereRaw("STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year, '-', month, '-', 1), '%Y-%m-%d') <= ?", "$toYear-$toMonth-1")
        ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->paginate(6);
```

Answer (score 5):

use [whereBetween](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses) method here

```
Revenue::whereBetween('year', [$fromYear, $toYear])
    ->whereBetween('month', [$fromMonth, $toMonth])
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->paginate(6);
```

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: @Rwd yes i have tested .

Answer (score 0):

Try using Laravel collection's [whereBetween](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-wherebetween).

```
$data = Revenue::whereBetween('month',[$fromMonth, $toMonth])
    ->whereBetween('year',[$fromYear, $toYear])
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->paginate(6);
```